# Differentiation with polar coordinates

Tags: derivatives, mathematical-physics, polar-coordinates

[image]

I'm sorry if this is supposed to be something basic but I'm not being able to understand if r is as given above, how have they worked out r dot? What have they differentiated the x,y and z coordinates with respect to? r dot means r differentiated with respect to what?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's probably a [derivative with respect to time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_derivative) ($\dot{x} = \tfrac{dx}{dt}$) where both $r$ and $\theta$ are considered to be time-dependent, so the product rule is applied.

Comment: Both $r$ and $\theta$ are functions of a single parameter (e.g., time).

Comment: Also: $r$ with an underscore is different from $r$, which may be obvious to everyone but me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrate first on the $x$ parameterisation. Write
$$x(r(t), \theta(t)) = r(t) \cos (\theta(t))$$

Remember that the product rule for differentiation is
$$\frac{d}{dt}(uv) = u\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{du}{dt}$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \dot{x} \\
              &= \frac{d}{dt}(r \cos \theta ) \\
              &= \frac{dr}{dt}\cos \theta + r \frac{d}{dt}\cos \theta \\
              &= \frac{dr}{dt}\cos \theta - r \sin \theta \frac{d \theta}{dt} \\
              &= \dot{r}\cos \theta - r \dot{\theta} \sin \theta
\end{align}
And the remaining two derivatives can be found similarly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $\underline {r}$ is a vector in the $x-y$ plane expressed in polar coordinates with $r$ and $\theta$ depending on a same parameter $t$ (it can be the time). The notation $\dot r$ and $\dot \theta$ are used to indicate the derivative with respect the parameter $t$ and the chain rule is applied to the components of the vector.